# Bootstrap simple layout is not responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Please excuse this newby question about Bootstap responsive layout. I am just trying my hand at a layout using what I think is a fluid nested grid. I have put gory background colours on all columns so I can see where they start and end. The layout looks good but if I resize the browser by making it narrower, I would expect at some stage the rightmost fieldset moves in below the yellow one as the space gets narrower. However, both columns just get narrower. I am probably lacking some basic understanding, and would really appreciate any help. Here is my full page code:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
<body>
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
  <a class="brand" href="#">Your Company</a>
  <div class="navbar-content">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Home</a> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span2" style="background-color:aqua">
  <ul class="nav  nav-list nav-stacked">
    <li class="nav-header">SETTINGS</li>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">Subnavigation One</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Subnavigation Two</a> 
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
   <div class="span10">
    <form>
    <div class="row-fluid" style="background-color:gray">
    <h2 class="page-header">Heading in div .row-fluid within a div .span10</h2>  

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span5">
                <fieldset style="background-color:yellow">
                    <legend>Yellow Fieldset, in a div .span5</legend>
                    <label>Label name</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…"/>
                    <span class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</span>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                      <input type="checkbox" /> Check me out
                    </label>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
             <div class="span7">
                <fieldset style="background-color:green">
                    <legend>Green Field Set, in a div .span7</legend>
                    <label>Label name</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…"/>
                    <span class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</span>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                      <input type="checkbox" /> Check me out
                    </label>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
 <!-- Le javascript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. The bootstrap responsive stylesheet should come AFTER the default bootstrap one it seems (and makes sense). So put this:

```
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

AFTER this:

```
   <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Sorry, beginner mistake.